# CS1061: MyClass does not contain a definition for X and no extension method X accepting a first argument of type MyClass could be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

### HttpParseException error CS1061: 'mcl959.Person' does not contain a definition for 'HasEmail' and no extension method 'HasEmail' accepting a first argument of type 'mcl959.Person' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am getting the above [Compiler Error CS1061](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061) for my ASP.NET web site build using .NET Framework 4.5.2.

I understand the error, but I do not understand why I am getting it.

Here is my StackTrace, showing that the error occurs in `Site1.Master.cs` Line 590:

> c:\Development\mcl959\Site1.Master.cs(590): error CS1061: 'mcl959.Person' does not contain a definition for 'HasEmail' and no extension method 'HasEmail' accepting a first argument of type 'mcl959.Person' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> Source: System.Web
> HResult:    -2147467259
> HelpLink:
> StackTrace:
> at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex)
> at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)
> at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
> at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)
> at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal()
> at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()
> at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
> at
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
> at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
> at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
> at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path)
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Below is a screenshot including Line 590, highlighted, with *Intelliscence* showing the definition of ***HasEmail***:

[image: Line 590]

And below is a screenshot showing project **mcl959** with class **Person** and my two (2) versions of the **HasEmail** function (the top one never got used):

[image: HasEmail]

The **CS1061** error is caused when you try to call a method or access a class member that does not exist. As I have shown, it does exist in my code.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Does this actually run? Note if you are using resharper caches can get out of sync. Also this is a fairly badly formatted and hewn question for someone with such a high rep. If using resharper try going into `Tools->Options->Resharper` then suspend and resume it. it will likely refresh the caches

Comment: Have you recompiled the app and restarted IIS?

Comment: @mjwills, several times. This bug has been preventing me from running the code for just over a week now. I even went into the folders and manually deleted all of the `bin` and `obj` folders so that Visual Studio was forced to recreate all of the dependencies.

Comment: @TheGeneral I do not have Resharper. If you have any recommendations for clarifying this question, please send them along. The compiler does not complain during the build. It compiles and runs, but the exception is thrown when the project starts. I'm confused.

Comment: @TheGeneral I'll put a bounty on this if it doesn't get an answer - provided others don't want to close it too before the time requirement is met.

Comment: @TheGeneral and my high req is from my work in WinForms. I really don't know squat about WebForms/ASP.NET

Comment: Is the Person and the Login_Click() method in the same assembly?  I see you have the HasEmail marked as internal.  Also is the Person a partial class?

Comment: @DCCoder - yes they are. Both are in `mcl959`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is an ASP web forms site (not an asp web forms application), it will compile the webpages only at runtime, on demand. That may be the reason that you're getting the error only at runtime, not in compilation time.

As of the error itselft, my guess would be that the lambda function is not executing in the same assembly as the class/method is defined. As it's marked as internal, it will throw that error.

Read more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal

Comment: Interesting. So simply changing **HasEmail** to *public* might solve all of this. That's crazy, but it will be easy to check. I'll get back with you shortly.

Comment: That was it, but I don't understand why Visual Studio compiled with a variable that was not accessible. The compiler should have caught that! Right?

Comment: Maybe visual studio only checks for namespace but as asp site pages compile on the fly, it falls in a different assembly.

Answer (score 2):

I used to get this problem when I Developed using WebForms.

This could only be applicable if your web project is a "Web Site" project and not a "Web Application" project. Might even work if it is a web Application project but I doubt it, it is worth a try.

"Web Site" projects normally don't need compiled dlls when you deploy the site or run it locally while you debug. The site gets compiled on the fly.

The compiled dlls will go to the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folder. If you delete these files then it should work. It could be that these compiled dlls is not updated.

Try clearing the files in these folders

`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

This folder might not exist but if it does clear it

`%AppData%\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

You might need to close Visual studio and if you are using IIS then it might also be a good idea to stop IIS.

Read more about dynamic compilation here:
[Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms366723(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: I found a link earlier that mentioned deleting the files in the `AppData/Local/Temp` folder. I did that, but it did not help. I'm going to try looking for those folders as soon as I get home in about 2 hours. Fingers crossed!

Comment: The biggest hurtle was the `internal` variable declaration. For some reason, Visual Studio's compiler didn't complain about it. That's irritating. I'll add 50 for this one too after I can award a bounty.